# restFB: Facebook login redirect

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token, restfb

i've tried to request 
 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_API_KEY& redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_stream,create_event

but i'm getting an error after redirection: 
"The requested URL /login.php?login_attempt=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook...."

where did login.php come from, that is not the redirection page?!
what is the problem at redirection?
thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us the Java code making the request, and the full error message?

Answer (score 4):

The `redirect_uri` should be a URL on **your server** where facebook will redirect the user after he/she granted you access to his/her protected resources. There you should exchange the **request token**--the value of the `code` querystring parameter returned from facebook--for the `access_token` with a server-side fetch.

The `redirect_uri` must be on the same domain as the **Site URL** setting on the **Website with Facebook Login** in the facebook application setting at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your-app-id}/summary/`

1. Redirect the user to the provider

---

Redirect the user to the provider so he/she can tell the provider that he/she is giving you access to his/hers protected resources which you specified in the `scope`. After the user gives consent or rejects, the provider will redirect the user to the `redirect_uri` on your server. To prevent cross site scripting request forgery, you should generate and store a CSRF token and send it with the request.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={your-app-id}&
    redirect_uri=http://your-site.com/after-redirect&
    scope=list,of,scopes&
    state={a-hard-to-guess-random-csrf-token}
```

2. Exchange the request token (code) for access token

---

In the request handler at `http://your-site.com/after-redirect` you should check the `error` and `error_message` request params. If there are no errors, you should first validate (compare with the stored one) the `state` CSRF token and if valid, then exchange the `code` (request token) for an **access token** by the provider with a server-side fetch. The `redirect_uri` and `grant_type=authorization_code` params are required (at least by some providers).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    code={request-token}&
    client_id={your-app-id}&
    client_secret={your-app-secret}&
    redirect_uri=http://your-site.com/after-redirect&
    grant_type=authorization_code
```

3. Use the access token to access the user's protected resources

---

If the *token type* is `bearer` you should sent the `access_token` in the HTTP headers in the form of `Authorization: Bearer {access-token}'`. See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?
    fields=name,birthday,photos.limit(10).fields(id, picture)&
    access_token={access-token}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
     public String getOauthUrl(String clientId, String callbackUrl, String scope) {
     return "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="
            + clientId + "&display=page&redirect_uri="
            + callbackUrl + "&scope=" + scope;
     }
```

Comment: what is the difference?it's only concatenation. tried it, same issue.

Comment: @user2482703 , you are not using display parameter.

Comment: @user2482703 you dont have to read the inputstream from the url, you directly have to redirect user to this url.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i'm using:

`URL url2 = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_stream,create_event");

URLConnection conn = url2.openConnection();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String test;

test=rd.readLine(); 

resp.getWriter().println(test);

rd.close();`

Comment: you dont have to read the inputstream from the url, you directly have to redirect user to this url.

Comment: @jhanvi can you provide more information?how do i make this redirection right?

Comment: You just have to paste the generated link on your brower , check what happens

Comment: i know. i saw that it works in browser, but how do i make it work from java?

Comment: You have to write response.sendRedirect("HERE THE LINK WILL COME"); , this way